# Visual studio Intellisense parameter summary

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

Ive used visual studio for years, but the answer this eludes me:

When intellisense pops up, for a method call that takes more than one parameter, the summary for the first parameter is shown. The only way i've found to show the summary for the following parameter(s) is to either supply each parameter or just hit comma until i get the one im looking for.

Ive tried ctrl+right arrow, shift + right arrow etc etc, without success.

Just curious is all.

Comment: this is extremely irritating! If a third party api has a method with many overloads, say ThirdPartyObject.Format(), I do not want to put 4 useless commas before I see the description of the 5 element. It should show overloads and their parameter descriptions like eclipse does (on pressing F2 I believe..)

Comment: Right click and go to its definition or view it in the object browser. Granted, both are painful compared to the quick tooltip view, but for methods with lots of parameters, it might be good to visit the "documentation" for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The requirements for each parameter are shown when your cursor is in the position that the parameter itself goes in. You can view the method overloads by pressing the up and down arrows, but you will still only see the current parameter requirements in the tooltip.

For more info, see [this page at MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/25cey46e%28v=VS.71%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Go to Options > Environment > Keyboard, type Param in the filter list, find "Edit.ParameterInfo" and bind shortcut keys in the Text Editor.

Alternatively, ReSharper remaps this automatically to Ctrl+P in its keyboard scheme.